# Remove 'duplicates' from a list of pairings

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

Title could be misleading, so an example:

I have a class:

```
class Pair
{
   Book Book1;
   Book Book2;
}
```

I have a list of these:

```
var list = new List<Pair>();

list.Add(new Pair() {
    Book1 = new Book() { Id = 123 },
    Book2 = new Book() { Id = 456 }
 });

list.Add(new Pair() {
    Book1 = new Book() { Id = 456 },
    Book2 = new Book() { Id = 123 }
 });
```

Now, despite the fact the books are 'flipped', my system should treat these as duplicates.

I need a method to remove **one** of these 'duplicates' from the list (any one - so let's say the first to make it simple).

**What I've Tried**

```
        var tempList = new List<Pair>();
        tempList.AddRange(pairs);

        foreach (var dup in pairs)
        {
            var toRemove = pairs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Book1.Id == dup.Book2.Id
                                                       && o.Book2.Id == dup.Book1.Id);

            if (toRemove != null)
                tempList.Remove(toRemove);
        }

        return tempList;
```

This returns no items (given the example above), as both `Pair` objects would satisfy the condition in the lambda, I only one to remove one though.

NOTE: This wouldn't happen if I just removed the element from the collection straight away (rather than from a temporary list) - but then I wouldn't be able to iterate over it without exceptions.

Comment: `dup.Book.Id`? Shouldn't these be Book1 or Book2?

Comment: @Vlad274 - well caught, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up an `IEqualityComparer<Pair>` concrete class and pass that to the `.Distinct()` method:

```
class PairComparer : IEqualityComparer<Pair>
{
    public bool Equals(Pair x, Pair y)
    {
        return (x.Book1.Id == y.Book1.Id && x.Book2.Id == y.Book2.Id)
            || (x.Book1.Id == y.Book2.Id && x.Book2.Id == y.Book1.Id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Pair obj)
    {
        return obj.Book1.Id.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Book2.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
var distinctPairs = list.Distinct(new PairComparer());
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are removing the both duplicates.

Try this:

```
var uniquePairs = list.ToLookup( p => Tuple.Create(Math.Min(p.Book1.Id, p.Book2.Id), Math.Max(p.Book1.Id, p.Book2.Id)) ).Select( g => g.First() ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following

```
    foreach (var dup in pairs)
    {
        var toRemove = pairs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Book1.Id == dup.Book2.Id
                                                   && o.Book2.Id == dup.Book1.Id
                                                   && o.Book1.Id > o.Book2.Id);

        if (toRemove != null)
            tempList.Remove(toRemove);
    }
```

This will specifically remove the duplicate that is "out of order". But this (and your original) will fail if the duplicate pairs have the books in the same order.

---

A better solution (since we're looping over ever pair anyways) would be to use a HashSet

```
    var hashSet = new HashSet<Tuple<int,int>>();
    foreach (var item in pairs)
    {
        var tuple = new Tuple<int,int>();
        if (item.Book1.Id < item.Book2.Id)
        {
            tuple.Item1 = item.Book1.Id;
            tuple.Item2 = item.Book2.Id;
        }
        else
        {
            tuple.Item1 = item.Book2.Id;
            tuple.Item2 = item.Book1.Id;
        }

        if (hashSet.Contains(tuple))
        {
            tempList.Remove(dup);
        }
        else
        {
            hashSet.Add(tuple);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution, but it's one I'm not happy with. It seems too verbose for the job I'm trying to do. I'm now doing an additional check to see whether a duplicate has already been added to the list:

```
 if(toRemove != null && tempList.Any(o => o.Book1.Id == toRemove.Book2.Id
                                       && o.Book2.Id == toRemove.Book1.Id))
                                           tempList.Remove(toRemove);
```

I'm very much open to alternative suggestions.

Comment: When doing a List.Remove you should watch for complexity. `Any` is O(N), `Remove` is O(N), and foreach is O(N), so you are in O(N^3) time complexity this way.

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy - yep, you're totally right, which is why I'm not happy with the approach. It was something to get it working (for now), but I'm not accepting it.